# Solving System of 2 simple odes

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Before I used euler method, it didn't seem a good approximation. Thus, I have shifted to ranga kutta method. I am just trying to solve two simple odes (dyanmical model) using Runge-Kutta method:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{dx}{dt} = v 
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
 m .\frac{dv}{dt}= f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x,v)
 \end{equation}

Consider the range to be from $t$ to $t$ + $\Delta t$.

But know not how to solve a system two equations using such a method. Can someone help me out here? Thanks, sorry if it seems trivial I have forgot much of basic numerical methods.

Comment: Before I used euler method, it didn't seem a good approximation. Thus, I have shifted to ranga kutta method.

Comment: Yes you are right! See [this](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy410-505-2009/topic3/lec-3-2.pdf).

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah I should have but $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are bit complicated to specify as such. They are functions of $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ of an particle and surrounding particles. If you specify the general psuedocode, it would quite helpful.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the link. Check it now if it makes more sense.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks again for the help. I solved it using your link. I looking the method to 2nd order using rk2. If happen know any link please recommend.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for link. Is there is example available somewhere if possible, that could help me understand better?

Comment: @Amzoti I am just looking for the psuedocode for rk2 solving 2dn order ode, I am not much of maths guy. Can you please the provide the psuedocode with a simple example solve if possible. It would it greatly helpful.